# NodeJS - How to use this 'object'?

Tags: node.js

So I've been 'fooling around' with the Steam port for Node.JS.
I've managed to get it to work with commands/user input, accept friends and so on.
Anyways, now I wanted to check users for their SteamID along with their profile name (which is supposed to be stored in "users"-object. I'm so un-sure on how to do this so if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it.

I really have no clue.

Here's the "documentation" on it:
https://github.com/seishun/node-steam#users

Answer (score 0):

It looks like once you connect, the client will just have a `users` array with all that info.

```
var bot = new Steam.SteamClient();
bot.logOn({
    accountName: 'username',
    password: 'password'
});
bot.on('loggedOn', function() {
    console.log(bot.users)
});
```

Comment: Modified my answer to log in first (undoubtedly required).

Comment: It only fills up bot.users & bot.friends once 'friends' is emitted (I.E someone removes the bot, or adds him as friend or alike) - how can I make it emit earlier?